# The probability of total number of rounds

Tags: probability

A tennis tournament has 5 rounds.After each round winners go into the next round and losers are knocked out of the tournament .

Roger inters the tournament ,Given that Roger is still in the tournament ,the probability that he wins the next round is a constant $p$.

The random variable $R$ represents the total number of round Roger wins .

Show that $P(R=2)= p^2 (1-p)$

My turn :
 I think the sentence "given that" means a conditional probability but i could not understand what does it mean concerning to the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(R=2)=\textrm{He wins the first round} \times \textrm{He wins the second round} \times \textrm{He loses the third round}$

$= p \times p \times (1-p) = p^2(1-p)$

Comment: (This is because all of the conditions must be satisfied, and they're all independent)

Comment: For the probability distribution , it would be : $P(R=n) =p^n (1-p) $ ? @Gareth Ma

Comment: Yes indeed @HussienMohamed (well for n<=5 anyways :)

Comment: If the player has to pay 10 dollars  to enter the tournament and only player who wins all 5 rounds gets a prize 260$ , what the expected profit of Roger in terms of p ? @Garetg Ma

Comment: @HussienMohamed $p^5(1-p) \times 260$...? what do you not understand

Comment: I thought about the same answer but it does not make sense to me @Gareth Ma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106046/discussion-between-gareth-ma-and-hussien-mohamed).